# luaotfload conflict with fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

After the most recent miktex update, the following code will not compile with lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The same error happens if I load the package luaotfload. On the other hand, if I don't load the fontspec package (or luaotfload), then it compiles fine with lualatex. So it seems there's some conflict there. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
FATAL ERROR
Luaotfload requires a Luatex version >= 0.95.0.
Please Update your Tex distribution!

...les/Miktex 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:36: version check failed
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'error'
...les/Miktex 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:36: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
[\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
1.49 }
```

I've updated Miktex and verified that I'm running LuaTex, Version 1.0.0 (MiKTex 2.9.6100 64-bit). Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this is a bug in luaotfload you need to get the fixed version from gitub. Ulrike has some miktex notes on this site, I';l find....

Comment: Thanks very much. I had seen that post but the problem seemed to be different than the one I was experiencing. All the same, the suggested fix in that post did address my issue as well.

Comment: well yes,  the question wasn't so clear (as the OP didn't report the first error that must have had,  But The answer is still the answer:-)